# GNU screen auto re-size with screen -x

Tags: session, shared, gnu-screen

Is there a way to auto re-size screen windows, along with screen -x option? I know we can do this by using the screen fit command, once the shared screen session is open, but is there a way to do this automatically? (just like with screen -r -d, the window is re-sized automatically). I am trying to open a shared screen session automatically, when a new ssh session is opened (by using the screen -x command in .bash_profile), this works; but the window is not re sized. Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 34):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html

> C-a F
>   (fit)
>   Resize the window to the current region size. See Window Size.

Note this is a capital F, so for me, it's ctrl+a shift+f

Comment: This is manual, but still better than nothing alright.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it myself, but looking at http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html I'd suggest starting `screen` with the option `-A`.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.